# Webscraping <li> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I wrote the following code to extract property details.

At the moment I am trying to extract the area.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Loads the webpage
r = requests.get("https://www.century21.com/for-sale-homes/Westport-CT-20647c", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
#grabs the contect of this page
c=r.content

if "blocked" in r.text:
    print ("we've been blocked")



#makes the content more readable
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

#Finds the number of proterty Listed
all=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"sr-card js-safe-link"})

x=all[0]

for li in x.find_all("li"):
    print(li)
```

Above code prints out the following

```
<li class="test-beds">6 beds</li>
<li class="test-baths">9 baths</li>
<li>8,511 sq ft</li>
<li>$370 / sq ft</li>
<li>On Site 2 days</li>
<li>Single Family Residence</li>
```

My question is how do I extract the data "8,511 sq ft"

I tried `print(li[2])` but unfortunately it did not work.

Can someone please point out where I am making the mistake and point me in the right direction to correct it.

Thanks

Comment: The site is protected by distil so 1. it shouldn't be scraped and 2. you most likely won't get the data this way due to captcha and certainly requests would not be reliable an approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `.text` to get the content without the tags. I also had it print both `li[2]` and `li[2].text` to show the difference

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Loads the webpage
r = requests.get("https://www.century21.com/for-sale-homes/Westport-CT-20647c", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
#grabs the contect of this page
c=r.content

if "blocked" in r.text:
    print ("we've been blocked")



#makes the content more readable
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

#Finds the number of proterty Listed
all=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"sr-card js-safe-link"})

x=all[0]

# Store all elements with tag <li> in li
li = x.find_all("li")

# Print the element in index position 2
print (li[2])    
print (li[2].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use css selectors to find it

```
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
number_li = soup.select( '.sr-card .js-safe-link ul li:nth-child(3)')
```